# Subversion+Apache authz not authorizing

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I am attempting to set up authz.  Actually, I had it working, but then I needed to move from Wable to Google Cloud, and while I was at it I moved from Debian to Ubuntu 18.04.  I'm also moving from Subversion 1.9.5 to 1.9.7.

I have a backup of the SVN config from Wable+Debian.  But just restoring my old files isn't working.

Anyway, I have a large single repo and I want the world to be able to read it, but for myself to be able to read and write it.  Also, I have a handful of directories that I want to be private and sometimes those directories need to be writable by an additional user.

My dav_svn.conf looks like:

```
$ sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^ *$/d' mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf
below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jul 21 09:22:58 AM PDT
<Location "/svn">
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

BTW, vim likes to color "REPORT" in red. I'm not sure what that's about - apache seems to pass its syntax check anyway.

And my dav_svn.authz looks like the following (I've removed some of the config to protect the privacy of others) :

```
$ sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^ *$/d' /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jul 21 09:23:52 AM PDT
[/]
dstromberg = rw
* = r
[/private-quizzes]
dstromberg = rw
* =
```

My repo allows me to change most files - that much is good.  But if I try to checkout /private-quizzes, I get an immediate:

```
$ svn checkout http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/private-quizzes
below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jul 21 09:26:32 AM PDT
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/private-quizzes'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/private-quizzes' forbidden
```

As you can see, it isn't even asking for a username and passsword.  It doesn't ask for them even if I remove my ~/.subversion .

What do I need to do to get it to try to authenticate me, so I can modify (for EG) private-quizzes again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Preface

Please re-read at least samples in this [SVN install manual](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_authz_svn/INSTALL) (pay special attention to "Example 2: Mixed anonymous and authenticated access" part - I used all time exactly this method without any troubles /when I was in Subversion/)

### Some additional notes

Just for simplicity

1. If you define some permission level at `[/]` you cam omit repeating it in subtree (i.e when you have rw in /, you'll automatically have the same level on whole tree below)
2. Even with `SVNPath` (i.e. single repository), I'll recommend to use common format for authz's file sections: `[repo:/path/in/repo]`. From the above docs, from "2. Specifying permissions" part

> This will work in the case of using SVNPath as well, only the
>   repository name (the last element of the url) will always be the same.

### Resume

I suppose

```
<Location "/svn">
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  Satisfy Any
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

will be perfectly usable for you and you can try list|checkout|commit to private area even without editing authz-file, but polished authz will be even better, after all